# How to connect Vue.js 3 to Laravel 10 project, send data to Vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, laravel-10

I am a beginner in programming, so I have issues with connecting these two things together. I understand how they work separately, but I wanted to add reactivity to my pet project.

I had tried this guide: https://dev.to/manuelojeda/pass-laravel-data-into-a-vue-component-without-using-any-http-request-c3j, but in the end, it throws an error that app cant open a js/app.js file in the Inspect Console ( ). Can you help me set up these two things together? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! It's helpful to add the relevant pieces of your code directly in your question. That way others will be able to quickly see what you've done. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/35566839) for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect Vue with Laravel by using `InertiaJS` **https://inertiajs.com/** .

With `InertiaJS` you don't need to make an `API` for your front-end, `InertiaJS` will take care of routing by providing a functionality that allows you to render your `Vue` components from server side just like `blades`, a `vue` component then can have its own resource controller, so you don't need to use `vue router` and you can build an `SPA` with server side routing.

but if you want to make an `API`, let's say for a web app and a mobile app, then you need to use `HTTP` requests to fetch data.